# Parallelizing Random Forest learning in R changes the class of the RF object

Tags: r, optimization, random-forest, parallel-computing

I am using the function `randomForest::randomForest()` in R to learn my RF.

First, I learned them without parallelizing and I obtain a RF object which was basically a list (and I worked pretty well when I learned the partial plots etc)

```
rf_full <-
randomForest::randomForest(sr ~ Lat + Long + AREA + Date + polypoint_ratio + time_span,
                           data = atlas_cart_data,
                           ntree = 500,
                           mtry = 2,
                           nodesize = 5,
                           keep.forest = T)
```

But then I realized it took too long. So I parallelized the script with the `foreach` package like this:

```
#Try to parallelize
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores()-1)
registerDoParallel(cl)

## Learn the RF
rf_full <-
  foreach(ntree = rep(500/length(cl), length(cl)), .combine = randomForest::combine,
          .multicombine = T, .packages = "randomForest") %dopar% {

            randomForest::randomForest(sr ~ Lat + Long + AREA + Date + polypoint_ratio + time_span,
                         data = atlas_cart_data,
                         ntree = ntree,
                         mtry = 2,
                         nodesize = 5,
                         keep.forest = T)

          }

stopImplicitCluster()
stopCluster(cl)
rm(cl)
```

**Problem:** now, the output is of class `Large randomForest.formula (16 elements)` and producing the partial plots seems soooooo long while it was quite quick before.

Note that the metrics (R², MSE...) are the same for the 2 methods. Thus, I really think it is a matter of class of the RF rather than the quality of it.

Did someone experience this already? Do you know how to greatly decrease the producing time of the partial plots from a `Large randomForest.formula`? Or how to have the former output out of the parallelized learning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradient boosting in R (xgboost) is widely used to instead of running and combining many random forest models.

Your question is not only about how to run models in parallel but also about how to combine different models. One easy way of doing the combination is just majority vote, i.e., treat each forest as a tree and do another level of random forest.

This approach is not ideal because the basic idea of the random forest is each tree is overfitting (low bias and high variance), the whole forest will reduce the variance and increase the bias. But if you are doing another level of majority vote, you may further reduce the variance and increase the bias.

Which means the final aggregated model may be under-fitting comparing with one random forest in whole data.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, parallelizing with the `foreach` package creates as many independent forest than I have cores right? It is indeed a problem, thanks for pointing at it. Now, I thought that parallelizing like this was merging everything and was acting like one learning process

Comment: I just realized that maybe the problem comes from using the `foreach` method. Just using the parallelization without spliting the task should produce a more precise output.